# Keep textarea active after message is sent

Tags: textarea

I'm creating a chat application with Angular and I got stuck on the following case:
When a user sent a message he has to click the chat area (it is a textarea) again to send a new message.

How can I keep the textarea active when a message is sent and the client to be able to write instantly after that without click the textarea again?

I tried to simulate a click (el.click()) on the textarea after the message is sent but it doesn't help. I tried also with el.focus().

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stuck on a similar case here is the solution:

```
el.focus()
```

should be done in

```
ngAfterViewInit()
```